# Disable 2FA for phpMyAdmin through terminal

Tags: terminal, mysql, phpmyadmin, two-factor-authentication

I set up 2FA for logging into `phpMyAdmin` but the token was deleted from my phone. Now I can't log into my database because it's requiring a code that I no longer have access to.

I've accessed `mysql` though terminal but cannot figure out how to disable 2FA from there.

Answer (score 1):

#### I've accessed mysql though terminal but cannot figure out how to disable 2FA from there

See this answer on Ask Ubuntu:

> You can reset the U2F(2FA) by deleting the row or the data in the
> phpmyadmin table `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig`
>
> `` sql DELETE FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE username='root'; ``
>
> See my comment on
> https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15433#issuecomment-521383779

Source: [I've Lost 2FA in PhpMyAdmin, how can i reset it? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171033/376050), answer by [William Desportes](https://askubuntu.com/users/432270/william-desportes)